# DataTemplateTrigger not working with datatemplateselector

Tags: wpf, triggers, datatemplate

I have defined a datatemplate that has a trigger that should simply change the background color if the item is selected. For some reason it doesn't seem to be working.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="existingDeviceTemplate" >
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Border Name="bd" Background="Green"  BorderThickness="1" Padding="5">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Width="200"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Settings" Click="cmdSettings_Clicked"/>
                        <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Delete" Click="cmdDelete_Clicked"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="true" >
                    <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Any binding errors? What Control uses this DataTemplate?

Comment: It is a list control, it looks like I have to set the style in the style sheet and use the data template selector to decide how to display different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to bind to the `IsSelected` property of the `ListBoxItem`:

```
<DataTemplate.Triggers>
     <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}" Value="true">
          <Setter TargetName="bd" Property="Background" Value="Red" />
     </DataTrigger>
</DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

*If your list control is a `ListView` you have to replace `x:Type ListBoxItem` with `x:Type ListViewItem`.*

Comment: I think you're right, the current code is binding to `ListBoxItem.DataContext.IsSelected`, and it sounds like the OP wants to bind to `ListBoxItem.IsSelected` instead, in which case this trigger should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Does your binded model had a property named IsSelected?
my guess is that you mean the rows' IsSelected property.
If thats the case you need to put a RelativeSource binding with FindAncestor to the ListItem